# Media de faturamento ignorando os dias zerados

Tags: javascript, json, matemática

Preciso calcular a media dos dias do faturamento que não estão zerados mas a função que eu retornei não estar funcionando, o resultado da NaN, sinal de que esta calculando algo?

```js
const faturamentoDiario = [

  {
    "dia": 1,
    "valor": 22174.1664
  },
  {
    "dia": 2,
    "valor": 24537.6698
  },
  {
    "dia": 3,
    "valor": 26139.6134
  },
  {
    "dia": 4,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 5,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 6,
    "valor": 26742.6612
  },
  {
    "dia": 7,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 8,
    "valor": 42889.2258
  },
  {
    "dia": 9,
    "valor": 46251.174
  },
  {
    "dia": 10,
    "valor": 11191.4722
  },
  {
    "dia": 11,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 12,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 13,
    "valor": 3847.4823
  },
  {
    "dia": 14,
    "valor": 373.7838
  },
  {
    "dia": 15,
    "valor": 2659.7563
  },
  {
    "dia": 16,
    "valor": 48924.2448
  },
  {
    "dia": 17,
    "valor": 18419.2614
  },
  {
    "dia": 18,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 19,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 20,
    "valor": 35240.1826
  },
  {
    "dia": 21,
    "valor": 43829.1667
  },
  {
    "dia": 22,
    "valor": 18235.6852
  },
  {
    "dia": 23,
    "valor": 4355.0662
  },
  {
    "dia": 24,
    "valor": 13327.1025
  },
  {
    "dia": 25,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 26,
    "valor": 0.0
  },
  {
    "dia": 27,
    "valor": 25681.8318
  },
  {
    "dia": 28,
    "valor": 1718.1221
  },
  {
    "dia": 29,
    "valor": 13220.495
  },
  {
    "dia": 30,
    "valor": 8414.61
  }
];

//Faturamento em ordem crescente

faturamentoDiario.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.valor > b.valor) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.valor < b.valor) {
    return -1;
  }
});
console.log(faturamentoDiario);

//Retirando os dias de faturamento 0

const filtrado = faturamentoDiario.filter(item => item.valor != 0)

console.log(filtrado);

function media(filtrado) {
  var i = 0,
    total = 0,
    ArrayLA = filtrado.length;
  while (i < ArrayLA) {
    total = total + filtrado[i++]
  }
  return total / ArrayLA;
}

var a = media(filtrado);
console.log(a)
```

resultado : NaN

Como posso fazer dar certo?

Comment: O que espera obter com essa linha `total = total + filtrado[i++]` ? Não seria `total = total + filtrado[i++].valor` ?

Comment: @AugustoVasques acredito que seja a parte em que ele salta para o proximo indice, onde ele puxa o proximo valor para acrescentar ao total

Comment: //Retirando os dias de faturamento 0 !?

Comment: @Motta pedem para que os dias de faturamento 0 não sejam contabilizados no calculo da media, ai pensei em filtrar e utilizar uma array somente com os dias que há faturamento que é o filtrado

Comment: Achei que seu problema era estar ignorando os valores zerados ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Como o Augusto tinha mencionado, o correto seria

> total = total + filtrado[i++].valor

```
function media(filtrado) {
  var i = 0, total = 0, ArrayLA = filtrado.length;
  while (i < ArrayLA) {
    total = total + filtrado[i++].valor
  }
  return total / ArrayLA;
}

var a = media(filtrado);
console.log(a)
```